# refer to the return type of a function as a type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, return-type, type-systems

I guess I already know the answer to this question (ie not possible), but I just want to be sure because it would be such a nice language concept.

I find that I prefer to write code that builds a return type on the fly like so:

```
function buildMyObject () {
    const c = "a string"
    return {
        a : 6,
        b  : c
    }
}
```

the compiler knows exactly what the type is of the return type, but can I refer to it in other places, for example

```
function useMyObject(myObject : buildMyObject*) {
    console.log(myObject.a)
}
```

(the asterix indicates that I would like to use the return type)

It seems that I have to revert to writing a 'type', an 'interface' or a 'class' which all feel like redundant code

Comment: 1. If you're reusing it, it's not redundant... 2. You can define a type as `myObject: { a : number, b: string }`

Comment: However, as @Oram said if you own `buildMyObject` I would *personally* write the concrete type definition out for readability/documentation purposes. It does not affect code behavior at all though.

Comment: Here you go: `function useMyObject(myObject: ReturnType<typeof buildMyObject>) ...`

Comment: great! Typescript rocks again. I'm really impressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neat `utility-types` library includes a [`ReturnType<T>`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#returntypet) for just this purpose.

**edit:** `ReturnType<T>` exists in the standard library, thanks [Aleksey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l)

Comment: While `utility-types` is indeed neat, `ReturnType<T>` is [included in Typescript itself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types)